# Constructing Regular Expressions to match numeric ranges

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a way to construct regular expressions to match numeric inputs specified by a given integer range, ie. if I pass in a range of 1,3-4 then a regex would be returned matching just 1, 3 and 4.

I wrote the following method to try and do this:

```
function generateRegex(values) {
    if (values == "*") {
        return new RegExp("^[0-9]+$");
    } else {
        return new RegExp("^[" + values + "]+$");
    }
}
```

I'm having issues however as sometimes I need to match double digits, such as `"8-16"`, and I also need to ensure that if I am passed a single digit value, such as `"1"`, that the generated regex matches only `1`, and not say `11`.

I really would like this to remain a pretty small snippet of code, but am not sure enough about regexs to know how to do this. Would be massively grateful for any help!

EDIT: I realise I wasn't clear, with my original paragraph, so have edited it. I realise the regex's that I originally generated do not work at all

Comment: `/^[0,3-4]+$/` matches a mix of `0` `,` `3` and `4` like `000,,,,34,000`. Definitely not what you want.

Comment: `0,3-4` => `/^[0,3-4]+$/` is wrong. It will match 33, 44. The right expression would be `/^[034]$/`

Comment: It IS feasible to do what you want... But it's quite complex. I would say half a day/a day of work. The first hint is that you have to replace `,` with `|` and the basic expression should be `^(piece1|piece2)$`

Comment: To make an example: a regex to match `15-45` is: `^(1[5-9]|[2-3][0-9]|4[0-5])$`. If the regex had to match `15-125`: `^(1[5-9]|[2-9][0-9]|1(?:[0-1][0-9]|2[0-5]))$` or, without using non-capturing groups: `^(1[5-9]|[2-9][0-9]|1[0-1][0-9]|12[0-5])$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a (sane) way to test integer ranges with RegExp. I believe you're fixated on RegExp, where there are much simpler (more flexible) approaches. Take a look at [IntRangeTest()](https://gist.github.com/1312184).

```
var range = new IntRangeTest('0,10-20');
console.log(
    "0,10-20",
    range.test("") == false,
    range.test("-5") == false,
    range.test("0") == true,
    range.test("5") == false,
    range.test("11") == true,
    range.test("123.23") == false
);
```

If you feel like it, you can easily add this to Number.prototype. You could also quite easily make this an extension to RegExp, if that's what you're worried about.

Comment: Aw man, I've just gotten it working with regex's! That a much better solution though, cant believe how much time I've wasted!!

Comment: There's a saying… »Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.« RegExp rocks - but certainly not for everything :)

Answer (score 1):

Regexes don't know anything about numbers, only digits. So `[8-16]` is invalid because you say match between 8 and 1 (instead of 1 and 8 e.g.) plus the digit 6.
If you want to match numbers, you have to consider them lexically. For example, to match numbers between 1 and 30, you have to write something like (other regexes exist):

```
/^(30|[1-2]\d|[1-9])$/
```

Answer (score 1):

I was sure it was 4-8 hours :-) In the end (and in its uselessness) it was a good exercise in composing Regexes. You are free to try it. If we exclude one use of `continue` and the use of the `Array` constructor, it's fully jsLint ok.

```
var BuildRegex = function(matches) {
    "use strict";

    var splits = matches.split(','),
        res = '^(',
        i, subSplit, min, max, temp, tempMin;

    if (splits.length === 0) {
        return new RegExp('^()$');
    }

    for (i = 0; i < splits.length; i += 1) {
        if (splits[i] === '*') {
            return new RegExp('^([0-9]+)$');
        }

        subSplit = splits[i].split('-');

        min = BuildRegex.Trim(subSplit[0], '0');

        if (min === '') {
            return null;
        }

        if (subSplit.length === 1) {
            res += min;
            res += '|';

            continue;
        } else if (subSplit.length > 2) {
            return null;
        }

        max = BuildRegex.Trim(subSplit[1], '0');

        if (max === '') {
            return null;
        }

        if (min.length > max.length) {
            return null;
        }

        // For 2-998 we first produce 2-9, then 10-99
        temp = BuildRegex.DifferentLength(res, min, max);

        tempMin = temp.min;

        if (tempMin === null) {
            return null;
        }

        res = temp.res;

        // Then here 100-998
        res = BuildRegex.SameLength(res, tempMin, max);
    }

    res = res.substr(0, res.length - 1);
    res += ')$';

    return new RegExp(res);
};

BuildRegex.Repeat = function(ch, n) {
    "use strict";

    return new Array(n + 1).join(ch);
};

BuildRegex.Trim = function(str, ch) {
    "use strict";

    var i = 0;

    while (i < str.length && str[i] === ch) {
        i += 1;
    }

    return str.substr(i);
};

BuildRegex.IsOnlyDigit = function(str, start, digit) {
    "use strict";

    var i;

    for (i = start; i < str.length; i += 1) {
        if (str[i] !== digit) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
};

BuildRegex.RangeDigit = function(min, max) {
    "use strict";

    if (min === max) {
        return min;
    }

    return '[' + min + '-' + max + ']';
};

BuildRegex.DifferentLength = function(res, min, max) {
    "use strict";

    var tempMin = min,
        i, tempMax;

    for (i = min.length; i < max.length; i += 1) {
        tempMax = BuildRegex.Repeat('9', i);

        res = BuildRegex.SameLength(res, tempMin, tempMax);

        tempMin = '1' + BuildRegex.Repeat('0', i);
    }

    if (tempMin > tempMax) {
        return null;
    }

    return {
        min: tempMin,
        res: res
    };
};

BuildRegex.SameLength = function(res, min, max) {
    "use strict";

    var commonPart;

    // 100-100
    if (min === max) {
        res += min;
        res += '|';

        return res;
    }

    for (commonPart = 0; commonPart < min.length; commonPart += 1) {
        if (min[commonPart] !== max[commonPart]) {
            break;
        }
    }

    res = BuildRegex.RecursivelyAddRange(res, min.substr(0, commonPart), min.substr(commonPart), max.substr(commonPart));

    return res;
};

BuildRegex.RecursivelyAddRange = function(res, prefix, min, max) {
    "use strict";

    var only0Min, only9Max, i, middleMin, middleMax;

    if (min.length === 1) {
        res += prefix;
        res += BuildRegex.RangeDigit(min[0], max[0]);
        res += '|';

        return res;
    }

    // Check if 
    only0Min = BuildRegex.IsOnlyDigit(min, 1, '0');
    only9Max = BuildRegex.IsOnlyDigit(max, 1, '9');

    if (only0Min && only9Max) {
        res += prefix;
        res += BuildRegex.RangeDigit(min[0], max[0]);

        for (i = 1; i < min.length; i += 1) {
            res += '[0-9]';
        }

        res += '|';

        return res;
    }

    middleMin = min;

    if (!only0Min) {
        res = BuildRegex.RecursivelyAddRange(res, prefix + min[0], min.substr(1), BuildRegex.Repeat('9', min.length - 1));

        if (min[0] !== '9') {
            middleMin = String.fromCharCode(min.charCodeAt(0) + 1) + BuildRegex.Repeat('0', min.length - 1);
        } else {
            middleMin = null;
        }
    }

    middleMax = max;

    if (!only9Max) {
        if (max[0] !== '0') {
            middleMax = String.fromCharCode(max.charCodeAt(0) - 1) + BuildRegex.Repeat('9', max.length - 1);
        } else {
            middleMax = null;
        }
    }

    if (middleMin !== null && middleMax !== null && middleMin[0] <= middleMax[0]) {
        res = BuildRegex.RecursivelyAddRange(res, prefix + BuildRegex.RangeDigit(middleMin[0], middleMax[0]), middleMin.substr(1), middleMax.substr(1));
    }

    if (!only9Max) {
        res = BuildRegex.RecursivelyAddRange(res, prefix + max[0], BuildRegex.Repeat('0', max.length - 1), max.substr(1));
    }

    return res;
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------

var printRegex = function(p) {
    "use strict";

    document.write(p + ': ' + BuildRegex(p) + '<br>');
};

printRegex('*');
printRegex('1');
printRegex('1,*');
printRegex('1,2,3,4');
printRegex('1,11-88');
printRegex('1,11-88,90-101');
printRegex('1-11111');
printRegex('75-11119');
```

Test here http://jsfiddle.net/dnqYV/

The C# version is here http://ideone.com/3aEt3E

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it seems that there are 4 main cases that I need to address:

- Single digits, ie `1`, would simply generate the regex `/^1$/`
- Multiple digits, ie `12`, would require the regex `/^12&/`
- Single digit ranges, ie `3-6`, would generate the regex `/^[3-6]$/`
- And finally, multiple digit ranges work in a similar method to multiple digits but with a range, ie 11-14 would become `/^1[1-4]$/`. These would need to be split into multiple regexes if they span over multiple start digits, Ie `23-31`  would become `/^2[3-9]|3[0-1]$/`

Therefore, all I need to do is identify each of these cases and create a compound regex using `|` like xanatos suggested. Ie, to match all of the above criteria would generate a regex like:

```
/^( 1 | 12 | [3-6] | 1[1-4] | 2[3-9]|3[0-1] )$/
```

Do other agree this seems like a decent way to progress?