# Regular expression to match range of dates with months included

Tags: python, regex, string, date

I need to match a string to identify if it's valid date range or not, my string could include both months in text and years in numbers, with out specific order ( there's no fixed format like MM-YYYY-DD etc ).

> ### A valid string could be:

`February 2016 - March 2019`

`September 2015 to August 2019`

`April 2015 to present`

`September 2018 - present`

> ### Invalid string:

`George Mason University august 2019`

`Stratusburg university February 2018`

`Some text and month followed by year`

I already looked into issues such as
a) [Constructing Regular Expressions to match numeric ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887157/constructing-regular-expressions-to-match-numeric-ranges)

b) [Regex to match month name followed by year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655476/regex-to-match-month-name-followed-by-year)

and many others, but most of the input strings in those issues seems to have the luxury of some fixed pattern for the month and year, which I don't have.

I tried this regex in python:

```py
import re

pat = r"(\b\d{1,2}\D{0,3})?\b(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|(Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?)\D?(\d{1,2}(st|nd|rd|th)?)?(([,.\-\/])\D?)?((19[7-9]\d|20\d{2})|\d{2})*"

st =  "University of Pennsylvania February 2018"

re.search(pat, st)
```

but that recognizes both valid and invalid strings from my example, I want to avoid invalid strings in my eventual output.

#### For input "University of Pennsylvania February 2018" the expected output should be False

#### For "February 2018 to Present",output must be True.

Comment: See [regex-to-match-month-name-followed-by-year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655476/regex-to-match-month-name-followed-by-year) for a simplified version of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This REGEX validate date range that respect this format `MONTH YEAR (MONTH YEAR | PRESENT)`

```py
import re
# just for complexity adding to valid range in first line
text = """
February 2016 - March 2019 February 2017 - March 2019
September 2015 to August 2019
April 2015 to present
September 2018 - present
George Mason University august 2019
Stratusburg university February 2018
Some text and month followed by year
"""
# writing the REGEX in one line will make it very UGLY 
MONTHS_RE = ['Jan(?:uary)?', 'Feb(?:ruary)', 'Mar(?:ch)', 'Apr(?:il)?', 'May', 'Jun(?:e)?', 'Aug(?:ust)?', 'Sep(?:tember)?',
             '(?:Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?']
# to match MONTH NAME and capture it (Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)...|(?:Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?)
RE_MONTH = '({})'.format('|'.join(MONTHS_RE))
# THIS MATCHE  MONTH FOLLOWED BY YEAR{2 or 4} I will use two times in Final REGEXP
RE_DATE = '{RE_MONTH}(?:[\s]+)(\d{{2,4}})'.format(RE_MONTH=RE_MONTH)
# FINAL REGEX
RE_VALID_RANGE = re.compile('{RE_DATE}.+?(?:{RE_DATE}|(present))'.format(RE_DATE=RE_DATE), flags=re.IGNORECASE)


# if you want to extract both valid an invalide
valid_ranges = []
invalid_ranges = []
for line in text.split('\n'):
    if line:
        groups = re.findall(RE_VALID_RANGE, line)
        if groups:
            # If you want to do something with range
            # all valid ranges are here my be 1 or 2 depends on the number of valid range in one line
            # every group have 4 elements because there is 4 capturing group
            # if M2,Y2 are not empty present is empty or the inverse only one of them is there (because of (?:{RE_DATE}|(present)) )
            M1, Y1, M2, Y2, present = groups[0]  # here use loop if you want to verify the values even more
            valid_ranges.append(line)
        else:
            invalid_ranges.append(line)

print('VALID: ', valid_ranges)
print('INVALID:', invalid_ranges)


# this yields only valid ranges if there is 2 in one line will yield two valid ranges
# if you are dealing with lines this is not what you want
valid_ranges = []
for match in re.finditer(RE_VALID_RANGE, text):
    # if you want to check the ranges
    M1, Y1, M2, Y2, present = match.groups()
    valid_ranges.append(match.group(0))  # the text is returned here
print('VALID USING <finditer>: ',  valid_ranges)
```

OUPUT:

```
VALID:  ['February 2016 - March 2019 February 2017 - March 2019', 'September 2015 to August 2019', 'April 2015 to present', 'September 2018 - present']
INVALID: ['George Mason University august 2019', 'Stratusburg university February 2018', 'Some text and month followed by year']
VALID USING <finditer>:  ['February 2016 - March 2019', 'February 2017 - March 2019', 'September 2015 to August 2019', 'April 2015 to present', 'September 2018 - present']
```

I hate writing long regular expression in a single `str` variable I love to break it to understand what It does when I read my code after six Months. Note how the first line is divided to two valid range string using `finditer`

If you want just to extract ranges you can use this:

```
valid_ranges = re.findall(RE_VALID_RANGE, text)
```

But this returns the groups `([M1, Y1, M2, Y2, present)..]` not the Text :

```
[('February', '2016', 'March', '2019', ''), ('February', '2017', 'March', '2019', ''), ('September', '2015', 'August', '2019', ''), ('April', '2015', '', '', 'present'), ('September', '2018', '', '', 'present')]
```

Comment: `Jun(?:e)?` = `June?`

Comment: @CharifDZ I wish I could give you likes in an infinite loop ! Thank you for a clear and precise explanation. This is exactly what I wanted. Shows your efficiency of coding.

Comment: @CharifDZ  I'd like to make one tiny change ( it's totally optional but would like to include this edge case as well ). I'd like to treat _pals october 2018 to october 2019_ as valid as welll, I changed re to `'([\w]\s)?{RE_DATE}.+?(?:{RE_DATE}|(present))'` but the above sentence was not treated as valid one, any suggestions on this ? Typically I want to treat `optional_word month1 year1 ( - or to ) month2 year2 | present` as valid.

Comment: What is the sentence exactly?  It looks like the other for me? why it's not matched!!  Can you post a comment with the sentence

Comment: @CharifDZ There was a typo, I already added `october` ,it worked, my bad !

Comment: We just forget to add `october` to `MONTHS_RE`, try `'Oct(?:ober)'`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you could reduce the boundaries of your expression with some simple ones such as:

```
(?i)^\S+\s+(\d{2})?(\d{2})\s*(?:[-_]|to)\s*(present|\S+)\s*(\d{2})?(\d{2})?$
```

or maybe,

```
(?i)\S+\s+(\d{2})?(\d{2})\s*(?:[-_]|to)\s*(present|\S+)\s*(\d{2})?(\d{2})?
```

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"(?i)^\S+\s+(\d{2})?(\d{2})\s*(?:[-_]|to)\s*(present|\S+)\s*(\d{2})?(\d{2})?$"
string = """
February 2016 - March 2019
September 2015 to August 2019
April 2015 to present
September 2018 - present
Feb. 2016 - March 2019
Sept 2015 to Aug. 2019
April 2015 to present
Nov. 2018 - present

Invalid string:
George Mason University august 2019

Stratusburg university February 2018

Some text and month followed by year
"""

print(re.findall(regex, string, re.M))
```

#### Output

```
[('20', '16', 'March', '20', '19'), ('20', '15', 'August', '20', '19'), ('20', '15', 'present', '', ''), ('20', '18', 'present', '', ''), ('20', '16', 'March', '20', '19'), ('20', '15', 'Aug.', '20', '19'), ('20', '15', 'present', '', ''), ('20', '18', 'present', '', '')]
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/jOrP75/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/jOrP75/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and code, I will try it out.